# How to read XML file in JMeter?

Tags: java, xml, jmeter, beanshell, readxml

I have tried:

`//${__FileToString(C:\\QC\\qa\\Testlink\\Jmeter\\Expected\\test.xml,ASCII,${xmlFile})};`

Found error message :
*``` org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/At . . . '' Encountered "<" at line 2, column 1. ```*

also, I tried with `${__StringFromFile}` and got the same error message and even with beanshell script that is:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

  //Open the file  
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C://QC//qa//Testlink//Jmeter//Expected//test.xml");  
  //Get the object of DataInputStream  
  DataInputStream instream = new DataInputStream(fstream);  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out the following:

1. Add [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into the sampler's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   try {
       String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:/QC/qa/Testlink/Jmeter/Expected/test.xml"));
       vars.put("content", content);

   } catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.info("Failed to read \"test.xml\" file", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```
3. Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan
4. Run the test
5. Make sure that Beanshell Sampler is green and `${content}` variable is set. If not - look into **jmeter.log** file and search for the line `Failed to read "test.xml" file`. If exception stacktrace below this line tells you nothing - post it here.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in your JMeter test.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be also helpful for anyone. JMETER also can use HTTP request to read the file from your local disk, credit goes to this page - you can use **"file"** in protocol field:

Like that (HTTP Request sampler):
[image]

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/extracting-data-files-jmeter

Comment: Please add the supporting condition into your answer, links get broken over time.