# In jmeter, can I use xml input as an alternative to the CSV Data Set Config config element?

Tags: xml, csv, jmeter

I'm looking for an alternative to CSV as input data and I think xml is the right format for me. How could I make that work?

I feel I'm 70% there already with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423876/how-to-read-xml-file-in-jmeter) answer. It stores the whole xml in a var 'content'. That's not what I need, but I would like to build on that example. I need the xml tags to be converted to a var, with its value (if any) as content.

What I need help with is: How can I convert every xml tag that was read, into an addressable jmeter var so I can use it as if I had read it using the CSV Data Set config element?

And I'll need to structure an xml containing all my testcases and their data in a way that make sense.

Example:

```
<testcases>
  <case>
    <name>tc1</name>
    <host>some.host.com</host>
    <command>uptime</command>
  </case>
</testcases>
```

Comment: It sounds like an enhancement. Is your XML dynamic? if not you can convert it even online

Comment: The goal is to apply this to a dev landscape in which the xml would be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [__XPath() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__XPath) which allows executing arbitrary [XPath queries](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) against files in the file system, you can use the function anywhere in your Test Plan.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Xpath Function Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Function concept if needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards this method. I'm trying to replicate your test, using a beanshell sampler (empty) with the XPath statements in the name. The logging shows that the node 'name' is found, but the value keeps being reported as `null`. I'm doing it wrong, obviously, but where am I going astray?